# Decode characteristic.getValue() in a BLE app

Tags: java, android, arrays, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a BLE (bluetooth low energy) app for Android.

So far I can read my characteristics with `characteristic.getValue()`.
But `getValue()` returns a `byte[]`. I know there are other functions (`getStringValue(...)`, `getFloatValue(...)` and `getIntValue(...)`) that return a `String`, `float` or `int` and this functions work fine.

But how do I know which one I have to use if I don't know which kind of value is stored in the characteristic?
Is there a way to decide this at runtime?

Comment: It really depends on the format you defined with your communication partner. For some characteristics the exchange format is defined in the Bluetooth Spec.

Comment: So there is no way to build something like a generic ble app that can connect to an any device and read/decode all the characteristics?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by that. There are LOTS of apps that can read the raw value. However the BLE protocol does not include the encoding so there is no way you can get a decoded value for a random device.